# How to restore postgresql db on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

I'm totally new to Heroku and Postgres and I'm trying to figure out how to restore and access the Postgres db in Heroku. I do have backup that taken fro pgAdmin III `.backup` file.

Any help with how to restore the Postgres db in Heroku would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This solution may be relevant to some people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433414/heroku-database-restore-issue/42435490#42435490

Answer (score 2):

Restore to local database

Load the dump into your local database using the pg_restore tool. If objects exist in a local copy of the database already, you might run into inconsistencies when doing a pg_restore. Pg_restore does not drop all of the objects in the database when loading the dump.
This will usually generate some warnings, due to differences between your Heroku database and a local database, but they are generally safe to ignore.

$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump

Comment: i have .backup not dump, how would i create dump?